# How to set a terminal-local variable in all terminals?

Tags: elisp

Specifically, I want to set `overriding-terminal-local-map` to nil in all terminals.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question: at creation it should already be nil, and at any given time, you should be able to `(dolist (t (terminal-list)) ...)` or `(dolist (f (frame-list)) ...)`.

Comment: It's nil at the start. Hydra sets it to non-nil for one terminal, then a user opens a new one with `emacsclient -t`. The new terminal has the map at nil, but the transient map `pre-command-hook` is still running. So there was a need to shut down the transient map on all terminals. And I did it with `frame-list` in the end.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that could affect set-transient-map as well, right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. The typical calls to `set-transient-map`, like `universal-arg--more` are harmless. The problem with the hydra was that it has a feature of disabling all commands that aren't in the map. So it became problematic when the map became nil in one frame after `emacsclient -t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a similiar problem and found out after studying the sources of Evil that using the `after-make-frame-functions` hook comes close enough.

```
(defun my-terminal-local-map-override (&optional frame)
  (with-selected-frame frame
    (setq overriding-terminal-local-map nil)))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-terminal-local-map-override)
```

For my specific usecase I needed to call the `my-terminal-local-map-override` function unconditionally additionally to that, so if it doesn't work for you in both Emacs and `emacsclient`, give that extra hack a try.